# Snowflake tables with TO, FROM as column names

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Looks like we've loaded some snowflake tables via ELT with "TO, FROM" as column names and they are both classic functions in any sql tool

Whenever I run a query for specifically those columns, there's always an error - how do I fix it apart from changing column names? Don't want to change column names as ELT process always happens from mongoDB via log based replication (stitch data)

select * - works perfectly , all other columns work too. Just "to" , "from" is the issue - should that never be used a columns?

```
select to, from  from table limit 10 ;    // tested [to, "to", 'to'] - none work
Error: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 invalid identifier '"to"'
```

Any ideas how to fix this apart from source column change or snowflake column changes?

Comment: Can you share the results of this SELECT get_ddl('table','mytable')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snowflake uses the standard double quotes to escape identifiers.  However, when identifiers are escaped, the case of the letters matters,  So, these are not the same:

```
select "to"
select "To"
select "TO"
```

You need to choose the one that is correct for your column names.

In addition spaces matter, so these are not the same:

```
select "to "
select " to"
select "to"
```

That is, what looks like `to` might be something else.  You need to know what that is to escape the name properly.

If you can't figure them out, there is a trick to create a view to give the table reasonable names.  Something like this:

```
create view v_t (to_date, from_date, . . .) as
    select *
    from t;
```

You need to be sure to include all the column names in the table in the column name list, in the same order as they are in the table.  Then you can use the view with reasonable names.

Comment: Thanks gordon, super helpful, fixed it - I was assuming case insensitive like we have for non-identifier column names